# Getting error while creating and downloading zip file in php

Tags: php, mysql, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to create and download zip file, but I want to zip the specific files in a directory which should be select from database.

What this program does is to select the homework files from school_homework for this subject only.

This actually create a zip file but when I extract it, it returns error 'this zip is empty'!

```
while($row_file=mysqli_fetch_array($run_file)){
$school_homework_file_file=$row_file['school_homework_file_file'];

  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $filename = "./homework.zip";

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
  }

  $dir = "$school_homework_file_file";

  // Create zip
  createZip($zip,$dir);

  $zip->close();

  }

  #Download Zip File
  $filename = "homework.zip";

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
     header('Content-Type: application/zip');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

     flush();
     readfile($filename);
     // delete file
     unlink($filename);

   }

}

// Create zip
function createZip($zip,$dir){
  if (is_dir($dir)){

    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

         // If file
         if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
            if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

               $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
            }
         }else{
            // If directory
            if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){

              if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                // Add empty directory
                $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);

                $folder = $dir.$file.'/';

                // Read data of the folder
                createZip($zip,$folder);
              }
            }

         }

       }
       closedir($dh);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @daveek. you are creating for every directory the same zip file and sending it to the user every time. is that right?

Comment: acutally the name of folder is homework, when staff uploaded homework for any subject, it stores there '../homework/80528242 - maths1.png'

Comment: I want that when forexample grade 5 student wants to download homework of maths subject, s/he can download all the assignment for this subject!

Comment: yes, but you cannot send multiple zip-files to the user at one time.

Comment: I don't want that, I want that in one director (homework/) zip only these .e.g. 5 files (name of files query from db)!

Comment: your "Download Zip File"-Section must be out of the while-loop.

Comment: I have to run a loop, to select * the files for a specific homework, that's why

Comment: maybe there are 2 files, or 5 files e.t.c, so want to zip them all

Comment: thats ok. In your while-loop you are adding the files to one zip-file. thats correct. You should take your download-section out of the while-loop.

Comment: done! now when I press download, get a blank page (nothing happens)

Comment: Can you see if the file is created? (without unlink)

Comment: $school_homework_file_file <- is this a file or directory? If this is a file, then the createZip function will not zip any data. See your "if (is_dir($dir)){" row.

Comment: no folder isn't created

Comment: $school_homework_file_file = ../homework/80528242 - english2.png ... (multiple files vary on

Comment: no luck.. can u please help me to figure it out

Comment: can you post the code again? there is curly bracket error. Is there any code before while?

Answer (score 0):

Change your createZip function:

```
// Create zip
function createZip(&$zip,$dir){
  if (is_dir($dir)){

    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

         // If file
         if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
            if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

               $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
            }
         }else{
            // If directory
            if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){

              if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                // Add empty directory
                $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);

                $folder = $dir.$file.'/';

                // Read data of the folder
                createZip($zip,$folder);
              }
            }

         }

       }
       closedir($dh);
     }
  } elseif (is_file($dir)) {
     if($dir != '' && $dir != '.' && $dir != '..'){
        $zip->addFile($dir);
     }
  }
}
```